# UWP - create_task crashed when running under Debug x64 instead of x86

Tags: visual-studio, asynchronous, uwp, task, c++-cx

I have the following asynchronous programming codes that are retrieving a file in a `UWP` app bundle:

```
Uri ^source = ref new Uri("ms-appx:///head.html");
auto getFileTask = create_task(StorageFile::GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(source));
```

When I run the code in `Visual Studio 2017` in `Debug x86` mode, it works fine. However, running it in `Debug x64` causes the app to crash with the following error:

```
HRESULT:0x80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
WinRT information: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

and Visual Studio breaks in the file `ppltasks.h` at this code:

```
__declspec(noinline)
~_ExceptionHolder()
{
    if (_M_exceptionObserved == 0)
    {
        // If you are trapped here, it means an exception thrown in task chain didn't get handled.
        // Please add task-based continuation to handle all exceptions coming from tasks.
        // this->_M_stackTrace keeps the creation callstack of the task generates this exception.
            _REPORT_PPLTASK_UNOBSERVED_EXCEPTION();
    }
 }
```

Any help?

Comment: What do you do with `getFileTask`? The `GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync` failed, but your code didn't handle the failure.

Comment: @RaymondChen Nothing is being done with `getFileTask` for the time being. How to handle failure? Enclosing a `try...catch` produces the same error.

Comment: An exception occurred in the `GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync` but you didn't handle it. You can see an example of error handling in the [FileAccess sample, Scenario 1](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/9ff70e120cf8a76c9128e6eca452c9b34632f443/Samples/FileAccess/cpp/Scenario1_Create.xaml.cpp#L33). You may want to switch from C++/CX (nonstandard extension) to C++/WinRT (standard C++). [Here's the C++/WinRT version](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/9ff70e120cf8a76c9128e6eca452c9b34632f443/Samples/FileAccess/cppwinrt/Scenario1.cpp#L34).